# Symfony3 - FindBy column from ForeignKey table

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have two tables: 'app_user' and 'user_parent'. User_parent have foreign key to app_user. I try show listing of users and needed informations are in both tables.

My input : `$data = array('name' => 'Sam', 'phone' => '799999999');`

name is in one of tables and phone is in second.
How I can do it in Symfony3?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: You should add your entity code here.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Doctrine

Get the object from the repo by a simple condition (e.g. name) like here

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

or use a dql query for complex criterias like here

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-dql

Comment: Thank for your help. It is a solution.